# delete sparx connectors with jscript

Tags: apache-spark, enterprise-architect

I have created a script that **automatically creates connections between various packages and elements**.

My issue is I ran the script several times and because there was no check to prevent duplicate connections I now have 10 duplicate connections for each element!

I need to

1. delete them all
2. find a way to check if connections already exists prior to creating them in the future

Here is my code to add the connectors

```
function AddC(myDiagramObject, myPackageObject, myElementObject) {
    source = Repository.GetElementByID(myPackageObject.ElementID)
    target = Repository.GetElementByID(myElementObject.ElementID)
    association = source.Connectors.AddNew("", "Dependency")
    association.SupplierID = target.ElementID
    association.Stereotype = "Requirement"
    association.Update()
    Repository.ReloadDiagram(myDiagramObject.DiagramID)
}
```

Here is my code that does not work to remove the connectors

```
function DeleteC(diagramObject)
{
  for(var c = 0; c < diagramObject.DiagramObjects.Count; c++)
  {
    var currentObject = diagramObject.DiagramObjects.GetAt(c)
      for (var d = 0; d < currentObject.Connectors.Count; d++) {
        currentObject.Connectors.Delete(d)
        currentObject.Update()
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: At a very quick glance, I think you need to move the Update() outside the for loop as it might affect the loop counter. Also, you might need to loop backwards from Count-1 down to 0 in case the Delete() causes the collection to renumber itself.

Comment: If I read this question correctly, you also want help with ensuring that no duplicate connectors are created. If so, please split that part into a separate question as it is not covered by the title of this one.

Answer (score 0):

As chimp noted in his comment, deleting an element in a Collection renumbers the remaining ones (those after the one you deleted). Looping from 0 upwards without taking this into account is therefore risky. Looping from Count - 1 down to 0 is much better.

If you want to delete **all** connectors, a cleaner way is to loop `while Count > 0` and do `Delete(0)` each time through.

More importantly, though, it looks like your code can't work as written. A `Diagram` has a `DiagramObjects` collection, but a `DiagramObject` does not have a `Connectors` collection - only an `Element` does.

As you can see, a naming convention which includes the word "object" in variable names gets confusing when there are classes in the API also named "object". Still, following this convention the following should work:

```
function DeleteC(diagramObject)
{
    for (var c = 0; c < diagramObject.DiagramObjects.Count; c++)
    {
        var currentDiagramObjectObject = diagramObject.DiagramObjects.GetAt(c)
        var currentElementObject =
            repository.GetElementByID(currentDiagramObjectObject.ElementID)
        while (currentElementObject.Connectors.Count > 0) {
            currentElementObject.Connectors.Delete(0)
            currentElementObject.Connectors.Refresh()
        } 
        currentElementObject.Update()
    }
}
```